# Processing form using jQuery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, sql

I need to process my form using jQuery (without refresh my site ) and using one buddon i want to add or delete row from my database .
Inserting to database works fine 
Deleteting too but i dont know what i need to do that after first click i add to database but after second click i delete row from database.

My FORM

```
<form action="index.php" method="post" id="myForm">
    <input type="hidden" name="option" value="com_mediamall" />
    <input type="hidden" name="task" value="addToFav" />
    <input type="hidden" name="addMediaId" value="<?php echo $media->id; ?>" />
    <input type="hidden" name="delRow" value="<?php echo $del->id; ?>"  /> 
    <input type="submit" name="submit" id="sub" value="1"></input>
</form>
```

jQUERY

```
<script>
  $("#sub").click( function() {
     $.post( $("#myForm").attr("action"), $("#myForm :input").serializeArray());   
  });

  $("#myForm").submit( function() {
     return false ;
  });
</script>
```

FUNCTION INSERT OR DELETE

```
function addToFav() {    
    $user =& JFactory::getUser();
    $db2 =& JFactory::getDBO();
    $mediaid = $_POST['addMediaId'];
    $delid = $_POST['delRow'];

   if(isset($_POST['submit']) == '1') {             
     $query = ' INSERT INTO `#__mediamall_favourite_media` (`id`, `userid`, `mediaid`) VALUES ("","'.$user->id.'","'.$mediaid.'")';
   }    
   elseif(isset($_POST['submit']) == '0') {     
      $query = ' DELETE FROM #__mediamall_favourite_media WHERE id = "'.$delid.'" '; 
      $db2->setQuery($query);
      $db2->query();
   }    
}
```

Will be apriciate form your help because i spend a lot of hours to find the anwer and without the result .. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

you need to use `preventDefault`

```
$('#myForm').submit(function(e){
e.preventDefault();
var url = $("#myForm").attr("action");
$.post(url,{data : $('#myForm').serialize()},function(data){
//process
});
});
```

and you can also use `json` to retrieve data from php so in your php file you can do

```
$data['res'] = 'ok';
$data['something_else'] = 'value';
echo json_encode($data);
```

Then process it like this

```
$('#myForm').submit(function(e){
e.preventDefault();
var url = $("#myForm").attr("action");
$.post(url,{data : $('#myForm').serialize()},function(data){
//process
console.log(data.res);
    console.log(data.something_else);
}.'json');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Toggle `submit button value` after `insert` or `delete` like,

```
$("#sub").click( function() {
  var url=$("#myForm").attr("action");
  $.post(url, $("#myForm :input").serializeArray(),function(){
      var val=$("#sub").val()==1 ? 0 : 1;// toggle value of submit for insert or delete
      $("#sub").val(val);
  });   
});
```

In **PHP** change your condition from **isset($_POST['submit'])=='1'** to **isset($_POST['submit']) and $_POST['submit'] == '1'**

**Code** like,

```
if(isset($_POST['submit']) and $_POST['submit'] == '1') {             
   $query = ' INSERT INTO `#__mediamall_favourite_media` (`id`, `userid`, `mediaid`) VALUES ("","'.$user->id.'","'.$mediaid.'")';
}    
elseif(isset($_POST['submit']) and $_POST['submit'] == '0') {     
   $query = ' DELETE FROM #__mediamall_favourite_media WHERE id = "'.$delid.'" '; 
}  
if($query)
{
    $db2->setQuery($query); //after if - else conditions
    $db2->query();
}
```

Comment: It works but without jQuery. When i run this with jQuery Button will toggle but wont insert and delete . what should goes wrong ?

Answer (score -1):

HTML

```
<form action="" onsubmit="return false;" method="post" id="myForm">
<input type="hidden" name="option" value="com_mediamall" />
<input type="hidden" name="task" value="addToFav" />
    <input type="hidden" name="addMediaId" value="<?php echo $media->id; ?>" />
<input type="hidden" name="delRow" value="<?php echo $del->id; ?>"  /> 
<input type="submit" name="submit" id="sub" value="1"></input>
```

JQUERY

```
$('#myForm').submit(function(){
$.post(url,$('#myForm').serialize(),function(success){
if(success=='success'){
alert('Data Sent);
// or do something else
}
});
});
```